# Error 404 converting .htaccess to web.config

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

My web server is IIS, so my .htaccess files don't work. Could you help me with the redirection and hiding the filename extension?
My code gets a 404 error.
I have two web.config files.

original .htaccess (1):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

web.config (1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewritePHP" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

original .htaccess (2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This web.config (2) works well (route the vhost to /public):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rewritepublic" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Details error 404:

```
IIS Web Core
MapRequestHandler
StaticFile
0x80070002

URL request: http://localhost:81/site/public/page1
Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\public\page1
```

Comment: "I don't have access to IIS Manager". You can always install IIS locally on a Windows machine and test out the rules.

Comment: Thank you, @LexLi I have installed IIS locally and my web.config(2) is working now. I changed the url ="/public/{R:1}" to "/site/public/{R:1} and it's ok" But the web.config(1) is not working